# Wronskian of orthonormal polynomials always non-zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that I have two orthonormal functions(with respect to the $L^2$ inner-product) $f_1,f_2 \in C^{\infty}(-2\pi,2\pi)$ on $(-2\pi, 2pi).$

Does this imply that their Wronskian does not vanish on the interval $(-2\pi,2\pi)$?

Answer (score 0):

No, the point-wise values of a function and their derivatives have only a very weak connection to the $L^2$ scalar products over the interval.

As such, the vanishing of the Wronskian, i.e., the linear dependence of the value-differential vectors, in one point is quite possible, even for orthogonal functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that the Wronskian could vanish at a single point. For example, take the functions $\{x^2,x^3\}$ (which are not normal but you can normalize them). Then:

$$W(f_1,f_2) = \det \left[\begin{array}{cc} x^2 & x^3 \\ 2x & 3x^2 \end{array}\right] = x^4$$

Which is zero at $x = 0$.

EDIT: Actually, it is even possible for $W(f_1,f_2)$ to equal zero everywhere: Consider $f_1 = x^2$ and $f_2 = x \cdot |x|$. If you want $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be smooth you can do a similar trick using bump functions. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are analytic I'm pretty sure it's impossible.